# What is the the most appropriate abstract noun to describe the relationship between a reference and its referent?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, abstract-nouns

I'm looking for a word to describe the concept of referencing or the act of referencing.

I'm configuring an issue tracking system that allows linking issues. A link is a pair of issues. These links can be configured to be of different types. This is useful to describe the meaning of a particular link – a link alone is too vague. For example, there is a link type called "Causality", with inward and outward relations defined as "A caused B" and "B is caused by A". Another link type is "Relation" which is a symmetric relation defined as "A is related to B" and "B is related to A". I need a link type name for "A references B".

Typically the word *reference* refers (at least, in my experience based on a programming background) to a specific reference and not the concept of referencing. For example: "variable x is a reference to value v" or "x references v". When I hear the word *reference* I assume an implicit "a", like "walk" as a noun seems to mean "a walk" and not the act of walking itself.

Is the act of referencing best called "reference"? Referentiality? Referenceness? Is there anything better/more appropriate than these terms?

More about abstract nouns can be found in this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/186660/232521) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Concrete_nouns_and_abstract_nouns).

Comment: _Reference_ is itself an abstract noun. What context are you thinking about? What do you want to say?

Comment: I think both of your examples hearken more to "ability to be used as a reference." What aspect of referential integrity are you trying to harness?  Is it the fitness for use as a reference?  Is it the authority of the reference?

Comment: Well, typically the word reference refers (heh) to a specific reference and not the concept of referencing (at least in programming background). For example: "variable x is a reference to value v" or "x references v". When I hear the word reference I assume an implicit "a", like "walk" as a noun seems to mean "a walk" and not the act of walking itself. So is the act of referencing best called "reference"?

Comment: @saritonin - looking for a word to describe the concept of referencing or the act of referencing

Comment: Are you specifically looking for something related to computer programming?

Comment: @saritonin - In my particular case, no, not programming. I'm configuring an issue tracking system. It allows linking issues. A link is a pair of issues. These links can be configured to be of different types. This is useful to describe the meaning of a particular link - a link alone is too vague. For example, there is a link type called "Causality", with inward and outward relations defined as "A caused B" and "B is caused by A". Another link type is "Relation" which is a symmetric relation defined as "A is related to B" and "B is related to A". I need a link type name for "A references B"

Comment: That is called a *resource*. Since A references B, B is a resource to A.

Comment: Perhaps these will get you unstuck (perhaps not...): "A references B" is a *citation*.  Maybe these will help: *citing*, and even *referencing*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarification provided, the link type described would be a **referential** link.  When A references B, they are said to have a referential relationship.

Comment: *Referential* is an adjective, and the OP asks for a noun. I think you should add the corresponding noun to your answer. Would this be "referentiality"?

Comment: @sumelic the two-word phrase is really the best way to describe the abstract concept, though I guess the noun form would be _referentiality_.